# javaFx aplication's start method

Tags: java, javafx

guys I have a problem here is my code that is a sample of Game Of 15 when I showed the shuffled scene as is shown in this picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LPEJ.jpg)

now I want to give movement form the user and change the scene and show it again until the game ends but when I put while after PrimaryStage.show() it crashes so my question is how to change the scene and show it again.

```
public class Q3 extends Application {
static Label lab[] ;
static Rectangle rec[] ;
static int X = 3,Y = 3;
static  int[] arr = new int[16];
public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException,terruptedException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
    Scene myScene = new Scene(root,301,301);
    rec = new Rectangle[15];
    lab = new Label[15];
    int x = 0,y = 0,Fit = 0;
    arr[15] = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < 15; i++){
        rec[i] = new Rectangle(20,20,75,75);
        lab[i] = new Label(Integer.toString(i+1));
        rec[i].setEffect(new InnerShadow());
        if(x > 3) {
            x = 0;
            y++;
        }
        Fit = (i < 9) ? 2 : 0;
        lab[i].setTextFill(Color.PERU);
        lab[i].setLayoutX(35 + x * 75 + Fit );
        lab[i].setLayoutY(31 + y * 75 + Fit );
        arr[i] = i;
        rec[i].setX( 1 + x++ * 75);
        rec[i].setY( 1 + y * 75);
        rec[i].setAccessibleText(Integer.toString(i));
        rec[i].setStroke(Color.OLIVE);
        rec[i].setFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE);
        root.getChildren().addAll(rec[i],lab[i]);
    }
    primaryStage.setTitle("The Game Of 15");
    primaryStage.setResizable(true);
    primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
    for(int i = 0;i < 1000;i++){
        shuffle();
    }
    primaryStage.show();
    while(!isfinished()){
       char c = in.next().trim().charAt(0);
       if(c == 'w'){
           do something
       }
       else if ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This simply isn't how JavaFX works: it is *event driven.* If you block the FX Application thread, it won't be able to update the UI. In a GUI application, it doesn't really make any sense to read from standard input anyway; the whole point of a GUI application is that the user interacts with controls in the UI. You should write event handlers that process the user events. (E.g. maybe you have mouse listeners on the tiles you create, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

Here is the sample code how switching works in javafx:

```
public class SwitchingScene extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
Stage stage;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {
        VBox layout1= new VBox(20);
        Button b1=  new Button("Goto Scene2");
        Button b2=  new Button("Goto Scene1");
        StackPane layout2= new StackPane();
        layout2.getChildren().add(b2);
        Scene scene2= new Scene(layout2,200,200);
        Scene scene1= new Scene(layout1,300,400);
        b1.setOnAction(e-> window.setScene(scene2));
        b2.setOnAction(e-> window.setScene(scene1));
        layout1.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Scene1"),b1);
        window.setScene(scene1);
        window.setTitle("My Window");
        window.show();

    }

}
```

I could not go through your code right now to understand what u have done, but u can refer to this code to see how switching works. On button action listeners I have done the switching.